# iOS dynamic tableview to have a border around it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a tableview in which the row height is dynamic as per its UILabel content (using UITableViewAutomaticDimension). Now, I need a 15 point border around the table view, that also changes as per the tableview height.

I tried two approaches -

- Took a UIView and placed the tableView on top of it with constraints
  as 15 on each side (top, bottom, left and right).
- Added four UIViews around the tableView with 0 constraint for each
  view to the tableView. (so that the views are always attached to the 
  tableView).

In both the approaches, the bottom view (or bottom area) is always giving a space in towards tableView bottom.

And to achieve the dynamic height to the tableView, I am using the below code -

```
open override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        if isPopup! {

            tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height + 190)

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Here are my Storyboard and the result on the simulator -

[image: Simulator Screenshot] [image: Storyboard screenshot]

How to make the bottom UIView always be attached with the tableView bottom, so it looks like a border around the tableView?

Answer (score 1):

Use your first approach and a custom table view subclass that uses its `contentSize` to determine its height. That way you can remove the code in your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and should be good to go.

```
class AutoHeightTableView: UITableView {

    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric,
                      height: contentSize.height)
    }

}
```

Comment: and how do I use this? am little confused!!

Comment: also, I get Type 'UIView' has no member 'noIntrinsicMetric' error

Comment: You simply have to create the class like above. Then in interface builder you have to set your table view's "Custom Class" to this newly created class. That's it. Regarding the error you are maybe using an older version of Swift. Try `UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric` instead of `UIView.noIntrinsicMetric`.